# Editing npm package locally in Angular 13

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, patch-package

I have an Angular app (v13.3.10) and I'm using the [ngx-markdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-markdown/v/13.1.0) package as a dependency. I'm finding a lot of bugs in this package. To fix this, I'm trying to edit it locally and view changes in-browser when running `ng serve`. But webpack seems to always take an unedited version of the source files in this package. (this package unfortunately doesn't have a `dist` folder).

Researching this, I tried both using [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) (setting a postinstall script) as well as disabling angular CLI's build cache. But no matter what, Webpack stays firm and doesn't apply local changes on `ng serve`.

Why does webpack not let me change source files to view in localhost? What else can I do from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to answer my own question here. The issue is that the ngx-markdown package is an Angular *library*. Angular has webpack configured such that no libraries are allowed to be edited. The best you can do is either:

1. Fork, make edits, import as a custom angular library
2. Send a pull request to the original repo and wait for a merge.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make the same changes that were made in src folder to the file in esm2020, fesm 2020 folders. Those are the files referenced by webpack.

Comment: The file I'm trying to edit specifically is `fesm2020/ngx-markdown.mjs`. These changes are not reflected by webpack when running ng serve. Not sure what you mean by changes made in src folder.

Answer (score -1):

1. Change your node module name
2. Then in terminal run `npm i`
3. Now you get new node module file
4. then run your code **ng serve**

Comment: What do u mean by "change the node module name"? `npm install` will just erase that change when it is run...

Comment: node_modules name to whatever the name you want to give

Comment: That's what I'm saying. Changing the name of `ngx-markdown` in `node_modules` is just overwritten back to `ngx-markdown` when I run `npm install`